# Drupal ignore the server permission and display permission error

Tags: php, linux, apache, drupal, centos

I have installed a Drupal site, after several custom changes I flushed all caches, but this action cause that sites/default/files folder do not have permissions and drupal canot change nothing under this folder, I have checked my CentOS permissions and all it's fine, 775 for all folders for user and group apache:apache,

[image]

775 for sites/default/files, I have tried 777 too and not work.!

[image]

But Drupal show me this message

[image]

What it's bad in my permission? thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If SELinux is active (`getenforce`), restore the file context (`restorecon -Fvr /var/www/html`).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with so little data.

1. Why is drupal trying to override an existing image?

   - Answer: Drupal isn't trying to override an existing image but create a new (the path does not exist)
2. What is the permissions on the file in question?

   - Answer: same as 1
3. Is the file in the public, private or temp directory?

   - Answer: public
4. Did you try to re-save the public/private/tmp directory locations (in drupal)?

   - Answer: Yes, didn't help

Comment: 1. the image and folder location path in error not exist, Drupal is traying to create not override.
2. the file and folder not exist
3. public
4. for the public files yes but not work